# https configuration in docker container not working

Tags: .net, docker, https

I have an angular application that uses a .Net Core web api as backend. The API uses https protocol.

I have been unsuccessful so far in getting it to run with that protocol inside a docker container (linux).

I have followed this tutorial:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/docker-compose-https?view=aspnetcore-7.0

When I run the app I see this:

[image]

7000:443  is supposed to be my https endpoint  ( on hover it shows http://localhost:7000)

When I type " https://localhost:7000" in the browser's address bar, the service comes up.

In the browser console, I see the following errors:

[image]

Here's my docker compose:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  meerkat:
    image: yyyy/meerkat:1.0
    ports: 
            - "8000:80"
    networks:
       meerkat-network:        
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
  meerkat.webservice:
    image: yyyy/meerkat-api:1.0
    ports:             
       - "7000:443"
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=xxxxx
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/aspnetapp.pfx
    volumes:
      - ~/.aspnet/https:/https:ro
    networks:
       meerkat-network: 
networks:
  meerkat-network:
```

Thanks for any insight on what I am doing wrong

Comment: It looks like your app is being coded to return the explicit URL of the containers name/host rather than just return a relative path so it maintains the same host address consistently from the browser.

Comment: Hi @ChrisDoyle, Thanks for the reply. Can you please expand a bit more? What do I need to change?  I am new to docker.

Comment: This is not a docker thing, its how your app deals with the return paths. You can use absolute paths or absolute urls. Most webapps will just return an absolutepath and use the hostname from the request so that its consistent with what the user sent. hoever it seems like your app is using absolute urls